# Convert from JSON to array of objects

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax

I'm trying to convert an array of Hazards(class that i created) to JSON,

this is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: web + "/GetHazards",
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        var res = data.d;
        var i;
        alert(res[0]);
```

the returned data is like this :

```
"[{\"Hazard_ID\":3014,\"Hazard_Lat\":32.2615929,\"Hazard_Long\":35.01423},{\"Hazard_ID\":3013,\"Hazard_Lat\":32.3426857,\"Hazard_Long\":34.9103165},{\"Hazard_ID\":3012,\"Hazard_Lat\":32.3426857
```

My server side code returns the correct values that i need, but the problem is when i alert the res[i] it behave like res is a string and alerts me "["

what i need to get is
{\"Hazard_ID":3014,\"Hazard_Lat\":32.2615929,\"Hazard_Long\":35.01423}

i dont know if it mind this is my server-side code by the way:

```
{
    List<Returned_Hazard> rh = new List<Returned_Hazard>();
    JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    .
    .
    .
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Returned_Hazard RH = new Returned_Hazard(
            int.Parse(reader[0].ToString()),
            float.Parse(reader[1].ToString()),
            float.Parse(reader[2].ToString())
        );
        rh.Add(RH);
    }
    command.Connection.Close();
    return json.Serialize(rh);
}
```

Comment: `data=JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: `JSON.parse(res)` <- Will convert the JSON to JS `Object`

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>), i tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON, using `JSON.parse`:

```js
var data = { d: "[{\"Hazard_ID\":3014,\"Hazard_Lat\":32.2615929,\"Hazard_Long\":35.01423},{\"Hazard_ID\":3013,\"Hazard_Lat\":32.3426857,\"Hazard_Long\":34.9103165}]"
};

var res = JSON.parse(data.d);
console.log(res[0].Hazard_ID); //3014
```

Comment: one moment I will try it

Comment: @كرمحاجيحيى No problem, please upvote and mark as answer if this helped.

Comment: Done, i have one more simple question, what i need to do to copy all of this data to a new array ?